# Getting "The project already contains a form or module named Unit1" error when creating new project

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I am using Delphi 2007.  When I try to create a new VCL Forms Application (**File->New->VCL Forms Application**) the IDE immediately responds with the above error.

I had this happen once before, and even thought I had asked for the answer on StackOverflow.  But for the life of me can't find the answer.  If I recall it had to do with an actual **unit1.pas** file being somewhere it should not have been.

Comment: Poking in the Delphi Options under Environment Variables BDSPROJECTSDIR is set to E, which does not exist.  On another computer we have this is set to "c:\documents and ....".  I tried an override but it still does not work.  And I searched in the system registry for BDSPROJECTSDIR but could not find where it is set to E

Comment: Strange. Have you recompiled the VCL or something like that?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera - Good point.  Yes - I did recompile a bpl. Not 100% sure, but it was about this time I started noticing this error.  So presumably they are related.  NOW - I can copy the compiled bpl to another computer and all works well.  So I don't think it is necessarily related to the BPL, but when I compiled the bpl perhaps I had messed up a setting.

Comment: Did you search your hard drive for `unit1.pas`? I'd suspect it's in the default project folder (which is in your `My Documents\RAD Studio` folder, IIRC), and there's a missing `unit1.dfm` to go with `unit1.pas` (or vice-versa, a missing `unit1.pas` with a `unit1.dfm`). It might also be an issue with an existing `Project1.dpr` that is orphaned. I'd do a search for `unit1.*` and `project1.*`, and move or rename the ones you find to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Did you installed IDE Fix Pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled up the problem.  **Tools->Options->Environment Options->Default Project** was set to **E**